# rake db:migrate syntax error (that doesn't exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, dbmigrate

`rake db:migrate` aborts because of a syntax error

```
rake aborted!
/Users/Fryed/rails/treebook/db/migrate/20121009215822_devise_create_users.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting '|'
/Users/Fryed/rails/treebook/db/migrate/20121009215822_devise_create_users.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

But the corresponding lines look like this:

line 3  `create_table(:users) do |t`
and line 47 `end`

Why doesn't this work, and how can I fix it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing a trailing `|`, line 3 should read:

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
```

`\n` means line break - so the error message basically said, "ruby saw a line break, but it was expecting another `|`"